# Changing two states with one button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to change two states with one button click. Ultimately I want to hide one component and unhide the other when I click a button.

The code works when changing one state, but not with two

```
import React from 'react'
import Buttons from './Buttons'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import SignIn from './SignIn'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Intro = () => {

const [showButtons, setShowButtons] = useState(true)

const [showSignIn, setShowSignIn] = useState(false)
const showSignInBtn = () => (showSignIn === false) ? setShowSignIn(true) 
setShowButtons(false) : 
setShowSignIn(false)

const [showSignUp, setShowSignUp] = useState(false)
const showSignUpBtn = () => (showSignUp === false) ? setShowSignUp(true) : 
setShowSignUp(false)




return (
    <div className='introBox'>
        <div className='titleMicroReactor'>
            CARDIFF MICROREACTOR
        </div>
        {showButtons && <Buttons showSignInBtn={showSignInBtn} showSignUpBtn=. 
        {showSignUpBtn}/>}
        {showSignIn && <SignIn />}
        {showSignUp && <SignUp/>}
        
        
        
    </div>
)
}

export default Intro
```

the showSignIn function is where it goes wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Your `showSignInBtn` is looking strange. Can you please check you wrote it correctly. No syntax problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular if else

```js
const showSignInBtn = () => {
   if (!showSignIn) {
      setShowSignIn(true)
      setShowButtons(false)
   } else {
      setShowSignIn(false)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need two states like `showSignIn`  and `showSignUp`.
Just check with one of them.

For example:

```
{showSignIn ? <SignIn /> : <SignUp />}
```

If `showSignIn` is true show `<SignIn />` else show  `<SignUp />`